# Leak above window frame. How to proceed?

Tags: leak, brick, rain

I live in a 15yr old townhouse that I bought 2 years ago. Roofing was replaced in 2018 by prev owner.

During rain in Dec 2022, I noticed that the lower right window (shown in picture) was leaking water from above the windowframe [image: House Front]

I called the roofing guy and he didn't see anything wrong on the outside. He did put some black silicone? On top of the curved brick window ledge (idk what's the name for it). No further leaks in 2023.

[image: water droplets]

Fast forward to rain this weekend and the leak returned. It rained for 30-40mins before the leak appeared, this time the droplets were falling faster than when the issue manifested in 2022. Eventually in 3-4hrs it filled up a 10 oz cup. Upon further investigation, the top window (3rd floor) I saw a slow drip as well, perhaps 6 drops of water in 4hrs. The middle windows are bone dry. I called the roofing guy again and he said the black silicone/putty he put in 2022 was still holding and the window in the middle 2nd floor was good, with no apparent gaps around it. He suggested keeping an eye on it to see if it leaks again, and if it's warm outside we can hose around the window/brick and cut drywall to find out what's going on.

I an confused and worried what to do. More rain is coming this week. Any ideas on how to proceed, what could likely be the cause, and best way to identify source?

Would home insurance cover this repair?

Thanks much!

Videos, 1st floor leak:
https://imgur.com/gallery/tLIAjmE
https://imgur.com/gallery/OM1HUAB

Comment: "Would home insurance cover this repair?" Depends on your policy, call your agent, we can't know. Water will run downhill until it finds a way out to where you can see it. The leak could be at the window, or it could be at the ridge and running down a rafter. The best bet is to get up into the attic, during the rain and look for wet tracks. That's the only way to know for sure where it's coming from. Once the source is identified, figure out the fix.

Comment: Home insurance might cover damage to your home due to a rainwater leak, but will almost certainly not pay for the repair to keep it form happening again.

Comment: I'd look at sealing up all exterior material joints (caulk/sealant).